# Как запустить python-скрипт GenesisH0 для генерации genesis-block?

Tags: python

Скрипт лежит здесь: https://github.com/lhartikk/GenesisH0

Фрагмент функции:

```
def create_transaction(input_script, output_script,options):
  transaction = Struct("transaction",
    Bytes("version", 4),
    Byte("num_inputs"),
    StaticField("prev_output", 32),
    UBInt32('prev_out_idx'),
    Byte('input_script_len'),
    Bytes('input_script', len(input_script)),
    UBInt32('sequence'),
    Byte('num_outputs'),
    Bytes('out_value', 8),
    Byte('output_script_len'),
    Bytes('output_script',  0x43),
    UBInt32('locktime'))
```

Ругается:

```
  File "genesis.py", line 74, in create_transaction
    Bytes("version",4),
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

, убираю ",4", ругается на следующую строку:

```
  File "genesis.py", line 75, in create_transaction
    Byte("num_inputs"),
TypeError: 'FormatField' object is not callable
```

Вопрос:
Что я делаю не так? Не та версия питона или надо расширение закачать какое-то?
Скрипт же написалии выложили, значит он у кого-то работал...

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно ничего убирать. Вот поможет:

```
sudo pip install scrypt construct==2.5.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Прога на питон2. Проверьте версию питон и пип.

python2 -V
python2.7

pip2 -V
pip 20.3.4 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
Библиотека пип2 должна ссылаться на питон2, как в примере

Загрузите зависимости
sudo pip2 install scrypt construct==2.5.2

Далее запускаем
python2 genesis.py -a scrypt -t 1616948461 -n 2000075705